# Pandas DataFrame KeyError 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recommendation-engine

I've tried to launch the following code using `Pandas`:

```
if USER_RATINGS:
  my_ratings = pd.DataFrame.from_records(worksheet.get_all_values()).reset_index()
  my_ratings = my_ratings[my_ratings[1] != '']
  my_ratings = pd.DataFrame({
      'user_id': "943",
      'title':list(map(str, my_ratings[0])),
      'listen_count': list(map(float, my_ratings[1]))
  })
my_ratings.merge(song_df_2, on="title", how="left")
song_df = song_df[song_df.user_id != "943"]
song_df = song_df.append(my_ratings, ignore_index=True)
if users.shape[0] == 943:
  users = users.append(users.iloc[942], ignore_index=True)
  users["user_id"][943] = "943"
print("Added your %d ratings; you have great taste!" % len(my_ratings))
song_df[song_df.user_id=="943"].merge(music[['song_id', 'title']])
```

However I had the following error below:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last)
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
-> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
[...]
KeyError: 1
```

Could you please help me to figure out how to resolve this?

Comment: `my_ratings[my_ratings[1] != '']` you don't have a column called `1`

Answer (score -1):

> my_ratings = my_ratings[my_ratings[1] != '']

Looks like 1 (Key) is not a column name (KeyError). If the purpose of this statement is to drop empty rows, try this instead:

```
my_ratings.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-896f40a7b3c1> in <module>()
      4   my_ratings = pd.DataFrame({
      5       'user_id': "943",
----> 6       'title':list(map(str, my_ratings[0])),
      7       'listen_count': list(map(float, my_ratings[1]))
      8   })

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: It worked and after that I got an error in mapping.